# Set Python Pub/Sub asynchronous pull subscriber threads count

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, asynchronous, google-cloud-pubsub

I implemented asynchronous pull subscriber using Python. This is the basic code

```
def receive_messages(project, subscription_name):

    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
        project, subscription_name)

    def callback(message):
        print ("A")
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Received message: {}'.format(message))
        message.ack()
        print ("B")

    subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)

    print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
```

I need to print like

A,

message

B

A

message

B

(I need to run sequentially) or receive messages via given no of threads. I don't find a way to limit no of threads. My program given **Segmentation fault** due to many threads.

How I control no of threads to receive messages.

Answer (score 1):

Problem can solve using Policy

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from concurrent import futures

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project, subscription_name)

def callback(message):
        print (str(message.data) + " " + str(threading.current_thread()))
        message.ack()
flow_control = pubsub_v1.types.FlowControl(max_messages=10)
executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
policy = pubsub_v1.subscriber.policy.thread.Policy(subscriber, subscription_path, executor=executor, flow_control=flow_control)
policy.open(callback)
```

We can set maximum thread count using **max_workers**. Also flow control settings can be set.

Comment: Hi, when I tried the above code, it started 15 threads and then it's restarting the processes one by one. I could not understand how it's doing that. Also, even if with 15 threads, it's taking up 100% CPU usage. Can you please help me explain this? Thanks,

Comment: Above code working for me. But if you use subscriber.subscribe(); method it add 10 threads in default. See 'receive_messages_with_flow_control' method in [1].  
[1]. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/pubsub/cloud-client/subscriber.py

Answer (score 1):

If you need your processing callbacks to run sequentially, you would be better off using a message passing model than modifying the subscriber internals.  If you push the received messages to an explicit [queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), you can ensure that only one worker is pulling off of this queue, and only one is being processed at a time. Note however, that while this provides you a ‘one at a time’ guarantee for processing if there is only one subscribing job, it does not provide you with any ordering guarantees.  Messages may still be processed in any arbitrary order relative to the order that they were published.

Answer (score 0):

If someone looking for a newer version

```
from concurrent import futures
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1


executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
scheduler = pubsub_v1.subscriber.scheduler.ThreadScheduler(executor)

with pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient() as subscriber:
    streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name, callback, scheduler=scheduler, await_callbacks_on_shutdown=True)

    timeout = 5 * 60  # seconds
    try:
        streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=timeout)
    except Exception:
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()  # Trigger the shutdown.
        streaming_pull_future.result()  # Block until the shutdown is complete.
```